# Checking If Order is Being Edited By Admin?

Tags: magento

My custom shipping module was failing because it couldn't get a sales quote when an order was being edited on the backend. This was the code I was using:

```
class Mymodule_Model_Mycarrier_Customrate 
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
        implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();
```

I need to get the current quote so I have access to the address information. I am making an API request that requires a street address.

Now if the order was being edited on the backend, this would obviously result in an error because the checkout singleton is no longer relevant. Instead I get the quote like this:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
```

In my collectRates() method I need to determine which singleton to load. First I want to ask if this is the proper way of doing things, and also if my check for the backend is sufficient:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();

// If admin is editing an order, find the quote by admin session.
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
}
```

I don't want this to potentially cause problems later. I also get the feeling that I may be using the collectRates() method wrong if I have to create a workaround like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` object already has access to the address via `$request->getDestStreet()`, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that! The default UPS module in 1.6.1 (Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups) doesn't use the destination street address in the XML request, so it didn't strike me as completely odd that I couldn't access the street this way. Cheers.